# peak next character in a file

Tags: python, iterator, iterable

I need to read a file in Python, where sections are enclosed by `/*!` for the beginning of the section and `*` for its end:

```
/*!Text
 this text is to be printed, but it can expand
 several lines

 even empty lines, but they have to be printed in the same way they're encountered

 this until a * character is found
*

/*!Another section starts here
  whatever
*
```

The objective is to print the lines as they're encountered in each section for now (then I'll have to do some processing). To read a file in Python I have something like this:

```
# open file
with open(filename) as fh:

    fit = enumerate(iter(fh.readline, ''), start=1)

    # loop over lines
    for lino, line in fit:

        if line.startswith('/*!T'):
            lino, line = next(fit)
            print(lino, line)
```

Now, instead of printing a single line, I would like to print as many lines until the new line starts with the string `'/*!'`. In C one would use the `peak` function, so is there something equivalent in Python?

**UPDATE**

So I may have done some progress when opening the file in binary mode (I'm using Python 3):

```
# open file
with open(filename, 'rb') as fh:

    fit = enumerate(iter(fh.readline, ''), start=1)

    # loop over lines
    for lino, line in fit:

        if not line:
            break

        if line.startswith('/*!T'):
            while True:

                lino, line = next(fit)
                print(str(line))

                char = fh.read(1)
                # back one character
                fh.seek(-1,1)
                if char == b'*':
                    break
```

But it seems to me there has to be a much compact way to do this in Python. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what's your need is. Could you give an example of input/output  ?

Comment: Done, I added an image describing a bit the problem.

Comment: An image of text ins't really useful. Would you type the text in, instead?

Comment: What Rob said. Also, does _any_ `*` end the section, or only if the `*` is at the start of the line?

Comment: Only if the `*` is at the start of the line. I modified the post to remove the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a regular expression:

```
import re

def get_sections(filename):
  with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.read()
  return re.findall(r'(?sm)^/\*!(.*?)^\*', data)

for section in get_sections('inputfile.txt'):
  print section
```

---

Alternatively, I might create a generator function that yields only the section lines:

```
def get_section_line(f):
  iterator = enumerate(f)
  for lno, line in iterator:
    if line.startswith("/*!"):
      yield lno, line.replace("/*!", "", 1)
      for lno, line in iterator:
        if line.startswith('*'):
          break
        yield lno, line

with open('inputfile.txt') as f:
  for lno, line in get_section_line(f):
    print "%04d %s"%(lno,line.rstrip('\n'))
```

---

Finally, here is a solution which maintains the section structure, in case knowing which section you're in matters:

```
import itertools
def get_sections(f):
  it = enumerate(f)
  for lno, line in it:
    if line.startswith("/*!"):
      yield itertools.chain(
          [(lno,line.replace("/*!","",1))],
          itertools.takewhile(lambda i: not i[1].startswith('*'), it))

with open('inputfile.txt') as f:
  for secno, section in enumerate(get_sections(f)):
    for lno, line in section:
      print "%04d %04d %s"%(secno, lno,line.rstrip('\n'))
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the enumerate into your solution? If something goes wrong when reading the file, I would still detect where in the file this happened.

Comment: I added an alternative, including line numbers.

Comment: I'll study your solutions. I think the first one is brilliant, simple, compact. Maybe I could also add the lino to the first implementation by somehow counting how many lines are in each section. About performance, maybe the second implementation is much better since you're using a generator?

Comment: +1: This is actually a nice solution. Best of all, it's easy to remove the lines that start with `/*!` if you wanted to.

Comment: @aaragon - I cannot think of a way to including line numbers in my first, regular-expression-based solution.

Comment: Well, you *could* do it, but it'd be insane. :) You'd have to enumerate on data.splitlines(), prepending the line numbers to the lines, join the list of lines back into a single string, and then process that string with a re-jigged version of your regex that can cope with the line numbers. Like I said, insane. :)

Comment: @aaragon : Generators aren't always more efficient. In fact algorithms using `yield` can be *slower* than conventional ones. But generators tend to be more efficient in terms of how much RAM they consume. Rob's first solution reads the whole file into memory before processing, which is traditionally faster than doing stuff line by line, however modern OSes tend to have *very* efficient file buffering.

Comment: So then if he files are rely huge, then the first solution will definitely break at some point, won't it?

Comment: Well, it'll still work, but if the file was too big to fit into RAM the OS would start using virtual RAM. Which is a bit silly.

Comment: @aaragon : If you don't need the line numbers, I'd _definitely go with Rob's regex-based solution. I wrote my version the way I did so it'd be similar in structure to your original version, so that it'd be relatively easy for you to understand, and also to give you an idea of where your algorithm was wonky.

Comment: Unfortunately, line numbers are a must, so I think I'll adopt Rob's second solution. But I still need to check the code.

Comment: @Robᵩ I ended up taking your last suggestion, but the code doesn't work if the sections are just enclosed by a single `*` character, in the sense `*HEADER\nSECTION\n*HEADER2\nSECTION2...`. It seems that in this case the `itertools.takewhile` consumes the header of the following section, so what I have in the end is that I can recognize only _odd_ sections, and _even_ sections are removed from the output. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You're bound to confuse things if you read & seek `fh` directly while you're in a loop reading it out of an iterator.

Anyway, this may give you some ideas...

```
filename = 'test.txt'

with open(filename, 'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if line.startswith('/*!'):
            while True:
                line = fh.next()
                if line[0] == '*':
                    #print '* End of section *'
                    break
                print line[:-1] #line already ends in \n
```

You don't appear to be using the line numbers, so I got rid of the enumeration